# Jasmine test fails making $httpbackend call due to angular mock receiving incorrect json format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm having trouble writing what I think should be a simple unit test.  I have the following controller:

```
 (function(){ 'use strict';
    var LoginController = function($scope, $state, RestService){
        var _user = {};
        var _message = 'hello';

        var _login = function(username, password){
            var _success = function(response){
                _message = response.success;
                _user = response.user;
            };

            var _error = function(response){
                _message = response.success;
            };

            RestService.postData('/api/login', {username: username, password: password}, _success,  _error, {showLoader: true});
        };

        $scope.model = {
            login: _login,
            user: _user,
            message: _message
        };
    };

    angular.module('danny').controller('LoginController',['$scope', '$state', 'RestService',LoginController]);
})();
```

Here is the spec:

```
describe('LoginController', function(){
    var scope, $httpBackend, controller, restService;
    beforeEach(function(){
        module('danny');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_, _RestService_){
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        restService = _RestService_;
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        controller = _$controller_('LoginController', {
            $scope: scope,
            RestService: restService
        });
    }));

    afterEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    describe('successfully logging in', function(){

       it('should redirect to /blog when authenticated', function(){

           var user = {"username":"danny@ravenartmedia.com", "password":"test"};
            expect(user.username).toEqual('danny@ravenartmedia.com');

           $httpBackend.expectPOST('/api/login', user);

           scope.model.login(user);
           $httpBackend.flush();
           expect(scope.model.user).not.toBe(undefined);
       });
    });
});
```

When I run the test the karma output is this:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 9.0.1\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\nodejs\node.exe c:\Users\danny_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt test
Running "karma:development" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8)]: Connected on socket SWVDLzehlqv2Z3J0C2Av with id 62852294
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8) LoginController successfully logging in should redirect to /blog when authenticated FAILED
    SyntaxError: Unable to parse JSON string
        at fromJson (c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular/angular.js:1066)
        at c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1646
        at $httpBackend (c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1194)
        at sendReq (c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular/angular.js:9616)
        at c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular/angular.js:9331
        at processQueue (c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular/angular.js:13171)
        at c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular/angular.js:13187
        at c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular/angular.js:14384
        at c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular/angular.js:14200
        at c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1525
        at c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/src/core/security/login-controller.spec.js:6
    Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.9/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
        at beginPhase (c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular/angular.js:14738)
        at c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular/angular.js:14180
        at c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1557
        at c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/src/core/security/login-controller.spec.js:6
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.031 secs)
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.028 secs / 0.031 secs)
Warning: Task "karma:development" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

I ended up commenting out the angular-mocks line that was causing the error (line# 1646), and see that for some reason, somewhere, the data i'm sending is being formatted incorrectly.  This is the error output now:

```
    Running "karma:development" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8)]: Connected on socket xGP0gRaa3WEdNVw1DrQm with id 89049214
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8) LoginController successfully logging in should redirect to /blog when authenticated FAILED
    Error: Expected POST /api/login with different data
    EXPECTED: {"username":"danny@ravenartmedia.com","password":"test"}
    GOT:      username=danny%40ravenartmedia.com&password=test
        at $httpBackend (c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1196)
        at sendReq (c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular/angular.js:9616)
        at c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular/angular.js:9331
        at processQueue (c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular/angular.js:13171)
        at c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular/angular.js:13187
        at c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular/angular.js:14384
        at c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular/angular.js:14200
        at c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1525
        at c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/src/core/security/login-controller.spec.js:6
    Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.9/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
        at beginPhase (c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular/angular.js:14738)
        at c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular/angular.js:14180
        at c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/vendors/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1557
        at c:/Projects/dannyschreiber/public/src/core/security/login-controller.spec.js:6
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.032 secs)
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.029 secs / 0.032 secs)
Warning: Task "karma:development" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

The key piece of info being:

```
Error: Expected POST /api/login with different data
EXPECTED: {"username":"danny@ravenartmedia.com","password":"test"}
GOT:      username=danny%40ravenartmedia.com&password=test
```

Why is my json being altered?

Here is the postData function from the RestService, which I've used in many projects without issues:

```
var postData = function(url, params, data, successFunction,  errorFunction, config) {

        if(config && config.hasOwnProperty('showLoader')){
            $rootScope.showLoader = config.showLoader;
        }

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            params: params,
            data: data,
            cache: false
        })
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $rootScope.showLoader = false;
                if (successFunction === undefined) {
                    _defaultSuccessFunction(data, status, headers, config);
                }
                else {
                    successFunction(data, status, headers, config);
                }
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $rootScope.showLoader = false;
                if (status !== 0){
                    _processError(data, status, headers, config, errorMsg, errorFunction);
                }
            });
    };
```

**Edit:**
I was able to hook all of this up in plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/lJTx0ldR9nEnlYbU5pJd and the test passes....but the exact same code gives me the error I'm referring to in this post.  I'm running v. 1.3.9 of both Angular and Angular-Mocks.

Comment: It seems like `RestService` is not configured to post your data as JSON, but form-data. Where is `RestService` from/defined?

Comment: RestService is an utility service I've defined in a different project, which I've never had a problem with.  It's basically a wrapper around the $http service.

Answer (score 1):

Your helper method is defined as `function(url, params, data, successFunction,  errorFunction, config)`, where `data` is the third parameter.
Compare this to your invocation:

```
RestService.postData('/api/login', null, null, {username: username, password: password}, _success, 'Invalid login, please try again', _error, {showLoader: true});
```

Here you pass your data as the fourth parameter. So I think you want to remove one of the `null` values. Unfortunately Javscript does not warn about wrong amounts of parameters (just ignores them).

Edit:
Meanwhile you have edited your question, however your invocation of `postData` is probably still incorrect.
I've prepared a fiddle using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/qwteyak3/1/

The first invocation of `postData` gets the data as the `params` parameter. This tells `$http` to send it as form data. The second invocation passes it in the `data` field. `$http` checks data, finds an object and then sends it as a JSON-body.

When running the fiddle, Chrome's network tab shows me a request to `http://fiddle.jshell.net/echo/json?password=123&username=test` for the first invocation and `http://fiddle.jshell.net/echo/json` (with data in body) for the second.

I hope this helps.

Comment: No, that is not it.  I slightly altered the signature when I pasted the postData function code into this question.  The RestService service works fine, and the call I'm making is the correct call.  The error being returned is showing that the data is being sent, it's just being formatted incorrectly.

Comment: I do understand what you're saying regarding params/data, but the call is working as expected when I use it in the application...this is only happening on the test.  What do you mean the second request, I thought only  the one request, scope.model.login(user) was being called?

Comment: I was talking about the second request of the fiddle. In the fiddle I call `postData` twice.

Comment: Regarding difference between test execution and application: Do you have any global configuration of `$http` in your app, which is not in your test? Or does your backend also reply to non-json requests? (That would explain why your request *seems* to be working).

Comment: no, no global configs.  I have tests running on the RestService project, testing the RestService, and they all pass just fine.  Also, I'm very new to Jasmine and javascript testing in general, I feel like I'm missing something in the setup??